# Video iframe overlaps content - html/css

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html to display a video but it doesn't look right. Below is the sscreenshot, HTML and CSS. How can I stop the video from overlapping and be displayed correctly?

```css
.video-responsive {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

.video-responsive iframe {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<p>Watch the video recording to see the whole conference</p>

<div class="video-responsive">
  <iframe width="320" height="240" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UHpaxaJ-GgU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<br/>

<p>If you have any questions, please email us at contact@metis.com</p>
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the code for the image pleas?

Comment: The image is a thumbnail image which is part of the youtube video.

Comment: That is because you are using `position: absolute` so the parent height collapses to zero

Comment: @Turnip The issue is that if I remove the `position: absolute` the embed video disappears

Comment: The usual way to do this is to set vertical padding on the parent to maintain the aspect ratio of the video. Read this article: https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-video/#iframe-video-youtube-vimeo-etc

Comment: @Turnip your comment above with the link fixed the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute` and `height: 0` on the wrapper.

```css
.video-responsive {
  text-align: center;
}

.video-responsive iframe {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>Watch the video recording to see the whole conference</p>

<div class="video-responsive">
  <iframe width="320" height="240" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UHpaxaJ-GgU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<br/>

<p>If you have any questions, please email us at contact@metis.com</p>
```